# Having Trouble Running my Server.JS. Listening Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, server, port

Hello I am having trouble starting up my server.js. Every time that I would run node towards it. It wills always show this error "listening on *:3000". Here is my code for my server.js.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/chat', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('User Online');

socket.on('codeboard-message', (msg) => {
console.log('message: ' + msg);
socket.broadcast.emit('message-from-others', msg);
});

});

var server_port = process.env.YOUR_PORT || process.env.PORT || 3000;
http.listen(server_port, () => {
console.log('listening on *:' + server_port);
});
```

Do I have to use a different port or am I missing a line of code for this server to work? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

http.listen(server_port, () => {
console.log('listening on *:' + server_port);
});
```

try only this without socket io. If it works, add socket io code

Comment: Unfortunately it is still giving me the same error. Even if I add the socket io code.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: The same error is listening on *:3000 one.

Comment: this is not an error .. this is your console.log !
your express server is running

Comment: I am trying to run a real time web based chat application. But in my console log it does not show who is online. I feel as though my server is not up. It is just stuck with "listening on *:3000"

Comment: https://socket.io/get-started/chat see the full tutorial 
you will get it !

Comment: No problem. In final of tutorial you can acess the full code on github.